# ASP.NET Telerik Ajax update control from Server Side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have an Upload Control from Kentico that has a `EventHandler`

```
upload.OnUploadFile += new EventHandler(upload_OnUploadFile);
```

That `EventHandler` is called and I want to update a node in a `RadTreeView` from Telerik like this

```
void upload_OnUploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   AttachmentsControl uploadControl = sender as AttachmentsControl;
   treeView.SelectedNode.Attributes["Image"] = uploadControl.Value.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that the upload controls are created dynamically so I'm having problems when trying to use the `AjaxSettings` in `RadAjaxManager`.

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(upload, treeView);
```

The code wont work since I'm using the `LoadControl` method which does not create a class instance. Anyhow is there a fancy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

`AjaxPanel` or `AjaxManager` do not support upload control,
You can try flash based file uploaders like http://www.uploadify.com/.

Comment: That's not the point, the upload works, the treeview works what I need is a way to update the treeview when the upload finishes like I explained.